# Скрипт работает только в IE, посмотрите в чем дело!

Tags: jquery, javascript

Подключил на страницу галлерею для просмотра картинок.
http://www.sv-gallery.com/4/wr.html
Работает только в IE, Хром и рыжая бестия не хотят запускать скрипт, будь они неладны.
Три часа копался, даже скопировал полностью файлы библиотек и исходный код страницы с сайта с демкой галлереи (изменив конечно же пути). На демке работает во всех броузерах, а стоит разместить эту шнягу на моём хостинге - работает только на Эксплорере. Выручайте, в чем беда?

Comment: Достаточно открыть консоль, чтобы увидеть ворох ошибок. Скорее всего версия jQuery старая.

Comment: Fike спасибо конечно за наводку, но та же самая версия jQuery работала на сайте с демкой галлереи, откуда я её и вытянул. Ворох остальных скриптов остался от предыдущего "разработчика", но они на работу не влияют, я пробовал уже создавать совершенно голую страницу - проблема остается.

Comment: @WWWarrioRRRR ну да, `$ is not defined` конечно не мешает. Там jQuery вообще не грузится.